# Code optimization for real time application C++

Tags: c++, optimization

I got basic C++ lectures at university and I don't really know how I can optimize this line of code for real time application (I call this function every 5 ms for UDP packet decoding).

I would like to have some tips about this code :

- How can I improve it's efficiency (in time processing rather than memory) ? (declare variable in the UDPmanager class, use static variable, ... ?)
- I am using openFrameworks for doing this project. Would it be better to use core C++ function ?
- Any tips about my way of coding

Thank you in advance for reading me and answering.

```
    void UDPmanager::readPacket() { 

    udpConnection.Receive(udpMessage,100000);  
    string message=udpMessage; 
    static int count = 0;


    if(message!="")
    {
        vector<string> strSensor = ofSplitString(message,"[/c]");

         vector<string> strQoS = ofSplitString(strSensor[0],"|");

         unsigned int receivedNumber = atoi(strQoS[0].c_str());


       QoS_estimator(receivedNumber,message.length(),atoi(strQoS[1].c_str()));


            if(receivedNumber<=previousPacketNumber)
            {
                sleep(1);
                return; // No need to use this packet. (= means it was duplicated in the network, < means it doesn't arrived in order)
            }

        previousPacketNumber=receivedNumber;
        strSensor.erase(strSensor.begin());


        cout << "loss : " << packetLoss <<  endl;
        cout << "counter : " << count++ <<  endl;
        cout << "receivedNumber : " << receivedNumber <<  endl;



        if (strSensor.size()!=sensors.size())
        {
            ofLog() << "The number of sensors changed in the system !" << endl;
        }


        for(unsigned int j =0 ; j<strSensor.size();j++)
            // For each sensors start decoding
        {


             vector<string> strData = ofSplitString(strSensor[j],"[/p]");

        for(size_t i=0; i<strData.size() ; ++i)
        {
            static vector<string> value = ofSplitString(strData[i],"|");

            if (value[0] == "[/i]") // Duplicate initialization frame
            {
                break;
            }


            if (value[0] == "POS")
            {
                sensors[j].touchpadPosition.x = (float)atoi(value[1].c_str())/10000.0;
                sensors[j].touchpadPosition.y = (float)atoi(value[2].c_str())/10000.0;
            }

            else
            {
                if(value[0] == "TOUCH")
                {
                        for(unsigned int i=0;i<sensors[j].data.size();i++)
                        {
                            sensors[j].data[i].touch = (atoi(value[i+1].c_str()))==1;
                        }
                }

                else if(value[0] == "TTHS")
                {
                    for(unsigned int i=0;i<sensors[j].data.size();i++)
                    {
                        sensors[j].data[i].tths = atoi(value[i+1].c_str());
                    }
                }
                else if(value[0] == "RTHS")
                {
                    for(unsigned int i=0;i<sensors[j].data.size();i++)
                    {
                        sensors[j].data[i].rths = atoi(value[i+1].c_str());
                    }
                }
                else if(value[0] == "FDAT")
                {
                    for(unsigned int i=0;i<sensors[j].data.size();i++)
                    {
                        sensors[j].data[i].fdat = atoi(value[i+1].c_str());
                    }
                }
                else if(value[0] == "BVAL")
                {
                    for(unsigned int i=0;i<sensors[j].data.size();i++)
                    {
                        sensors[j].data[i].bval = atoi(value[i+1].c_str());
                    }
                }
                else if(value[0] == "DIFF")
                {
                    for(unsigned int i=0;i<sensors[j].data.size();i++)
                    {
                        sensors[j].data[i].diff = atoi(value[i+1].c_str());
                    }
                }
                else {
                     ofLogError() << "Unrecognized key: " << value[0];
                }



            }

        }


        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to optimize for speed or do you want to make it real time? The latter tends to be very slow.

Comment: If you want a review of working code you should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I think it's better to put your question on this board : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Creating all those vectors is using the heap and will add unpredictability to execution time. If you can know the size of the results or at least some possible maximum, you may be able to avoid the need for those allocations.

Comment: @nwp  
Do you want to optimize for speed or do you want to make it real time? Can you explain me the difference ? I will post the question on codereview

Comment: You don't need to split string beforehands; parse the string as you go and cut on all those costly splits (each one of these require an allocation for the "index" and one for each string). The only dynamic allocation you possibly need here is the initial sizing of the `sensors` vector; all the rest can be done statically.

Comment: @PaulRooney Thank you for your answer I will modify my code

Comment: Optimizing for speed means you want to get done fast, so you use the best hardware, caches and optimizations available and you measure your success by how long the computation takes on average (think games). Real time means you buy weak hardware that has an upper limit on the time every instruction takes (normal hardware doesn't have that), you avoid caches because they make the worst case worse and you measure your success by being able to compute the maximum amount of time a computation can take even when an error occurs, which hopefully is fast enough for your application (think airbag).

Comment: In other words, for _real time_, the _worst possible_ conditions have to be handled fast enough. Often, that means ignoring things that might make it faster some of the time, if they also make it slower (in a difficult to predict way) the other times.